# why ::operator keyword added before new for memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

while understanding things, i came across with below lines of code.

```
int *p2 = (int *) ::operator new (sizeof(int)); 
*p2 = 100;
delete p2;
```

I understand the logic and task, but why this **"::operator"** keyword added before new?

How should i read further regarding this?

I am aware with below lines:

```
p2 = new int;
*p2 = 100;
delete p2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) is a basic memory allocation function.  [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) allocates memory for an object *and initializes it*.

There isn't much difference for built in types like `int`, but the difference is crucial for non-[POD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType)(*) types like `std:string`.

```
int *p2 = (int*) :: operator new(sizeof(int));
int i = *p2;  // ERROR.  *p2 is not (yet) an int - just raw, uninitialized memory.
*p2 = 100;   // Now the memory has been set.

std::string *s2 = (std::string*) :: operator new(sizeof(std::string));
std::string str = *s2;  // ERROR: *s2 is just  raw uninitialized memory.
*s2 = "Bad boy";        // ERROR: You can only assign to a properly
                        //        constructed string object.
new(s2) std::string("Constructed");  // Construct an object in the memory
                                     // (using placement new).

str = *s2;  // Fine.
*s2 = "Hello world";  // Also fine.
```

*: POD stands for "plain old data".

Comment: thanks. gave me the precise idea where and what to explore and experiment. Will take ahead from here.

Comment: I think the second line is a bit misleading. It can be quite ambiguous when the lifetime of an integer starts, and certainly it would be valid to say `*p2 = 5`. The chief reason why `int i = *p2` is invalid is because `*p2` is uninitialized. The lifetime on an `int` can begin before its initialization, as demonstrated by `int x; /* Alive but unitialized*/ x=5;`

Comment: `*p2 = 5;` is my third line (well, I used a different constant).  But your example of `int x;` where `x` is *clearly* an int, but uninitialized is very interesting.

Comment: I wonder if `*p2=100` is *technically* UB, because we haven't created an int there (but it's hard to believe a compiler would mind).